# How do I expose a decimal value with Dropwizard Metrics via JMX?

Tags: java, dropwizard, codahale-metrics

I am working on a java application that does audio recognition. I need to know the average number of recognized packets, but in an application scope, not a process scope. After the recognition process ends, it returns to me the number of packets received by the application and the number of packets recognized (packets actually processed by the application).

```
final int receivedPackets = stats.getReceivedPacketsCount();
final int recognizedPackets = stats.getRecognizedPacketsCount();
```

Consider this example:
`Process 1
        Received packets   - 10
        Recognized packets - 4
        Avg Recog packets  - 0,4 (recognized / received)
Process 2
        Received packets   - 10
        Recognized packets - 6
        Avg Recog packets  - 0,6
Total avg recog packets = avg(0,4 + 0,6) = 0,5`

The problem is, I was trying to use the Histogram metric type, but it only accepts `int` or `long` values in the update method.
I've also tried to use the RatioGauge, but it doesn't have an 'update' method, you need to unregister and register it every time you want to update the values, thus losing the history.

So, how can I expose this decimal value ?

```
metricRegistry.histogram("AvgRecognizedPackets").update( ??? );
```

Comment: You could just multiply your avearge result by 100 and cast the result to an Integer.

Comment: Thanks @willome, it worked. On zabbix I had to multiply by 0.01 to show the decimal value.